# Change XML location for spring

Tags: xml, spring

When I put my XML file anywhere other than resource folder it gives error of XML file cant be found I am using

```
ApplicationContext red=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

How can I change the path and use the XML file elsewhere ?
I am using IntelliJ IDEA.